# How to Convert Date in the form 'Apr 012022' to yyyy-mm-dd in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Ex:
Input : Apr 012022
Output : 2022-04-01

I have tried below ways

```
1) SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Apr 012022','%Y%M%D');
2) SELECT DATE_FORMAT('Apr 012022','%Y%M%D');
3) SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Apr 012022','Mon DDYYYY');
4) SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Apr 012022','%d/%m/%y')
```

All of them are giving output as NULL.

Please help for the same

Comment: see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format for parameters to str_to_date. NB date_format is not appropriate since the date has to be a mysql date datatype.

Comment: @Jagrat Is my solution working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("Apr 012022", "%b %d%Y");
```

For more info on STR_TO_DATE check the below link:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: `%M` is a full month, use `%b` for the [abreviated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: @danblack thanks but I tried %M which was also working.

Comment: @danblack see this fiddel link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ac1d458160e3bc13fee2b7c47eb1518

Comment: `%b` works with guarantee whereas `%M` may work only...